# How do I upload photos with my Blogger posts via Google's .Net API Client Library?

Tags: c#, .net, api, blogger

I've been able to successfully post to my blog using this library, but can't figure out how to upload and reference images with the post (similar to how Picasa's "Blog This" feature works).

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way. The images uploaded on Blogger are first uploaded to Picasaweb. So you need to work on picasa as well as Blogger API.

You can try the following steps:

1. Create a UI to select image from your system.
2. Use Google Picasa API to Upload image.
3. Get link of the uploaded Image and add it to your Blog's HTML code.